# Buscar dados no BD ao carregar página

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou criando um site de buscas e tenho alguns links com determinadas categorias.
Preciso de um sistema em que ao clicar nestas categorias a página carregada possa buscar os dados no BD e exibir.

Sei que é necessário por a action no link, porém não sei como.

Comment: E qual resultado você busca, uma listagem de produtos dessas categorias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você fazer essa consulta, você pode fazer via GET que para essa forma de consulta é uma das mais usadas.

Primeiro você precisa determinar um ID para cada categoria, sendo assim cada link terá um href para **lista.php** e seu GET categoria terá um ID, ficando assim a parte do HTML:

```
<a href="lista.php?categoria=1">Categoria 1</a>
<a href="lista.php?categoria=2">Categoria 2</a>
<a href="lista.php?categoria=3">Categoria 3</a>
<a href="lista.php?categoria=4">Categoria 4</a>
```

No arquivo **lista.php** será responsável por receber o código da categoria e mostrar os itens que estão vinculados a essa categoria, ficando algo dessa forma:

```
<?php
//recupera o ID da categoria passado pelo GET
$idCategoria = $_GET['categoria'];

//consulta dos itens vinculados com a categoria informado no GET
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM itens WHERE categoria = :idCategoria");
$stmt->execute(['idCategoria' => $idCategoria]); 
$itens = $stmt->fetch();

var_dump($itens); //resultado da sua consulta.
```